# OpenVPN server with an OVPN client added to reach networks on another server breaks IPv6

Tags: openvpn, ipv6

I have a running OpenVPN server which provides clients connecting with IPv4 and IPv6 which works. I am trying to add an OpenVPN client to this system which connects to another OpenVPN server which can provide default routes, but actually I want this disabled for this client. The purpose of the OpenVPN client running alongside this server is just to provide access to some of the IPv4 and IPv6 subnets on that other server. When I enable the OpenVPN client IPv4 works fine, but the server itself stops being able to get any IPv6 traffic from the internet when the client to the other server is running.

The OpenVPN service on the server runs as `openvpn@server` and the client which connects to another OpenVPN server runs as `openvpn@client` and it's that last service which stops the server from being able to receive anything on it's IPv6 address for it's `eth0` internet interface. With `openvpn@client` stopped, IPv6 services like SSH and ping requests work but otherwise not.

This is the configuration for `openvpn@server`...

```
port 9976
proto udp
proto udp6
dev tun
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
keepalive 10 120
topology subnet
server 10.7.0.0 255.255.255.0
server-ipv6 fd0a:beef:b00b:cafe::/112
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
tun-ipv6
push tun-ipv6
push "route-ipv6 2000::/3"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.7.0.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS6 fd0a::beef:b00b:cafe::1"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
dh none
ecdh-curve prime256v1
tls-crypt tls-crypt.key
crl-verify crl.pem
ca ca.crt
cert server_emjWqXeJkx9FLowU.crt
key server_emjWqXeJkx9FLowU.key
auth SHA256
cipher AES-128-GCM
ncp-ciphers AES-128-GCM
tls-server
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
status /var/log/openvpn/status.log
verb 3
```

This is the configuration for `openvpn@home`...

```
client
proto udp
explicit-exit-notify
remote 139.218.29.235 1194
dev tun
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
verify-x509-name server_3UvQL2AfKLys5yTS name
auth SHA256
auth-nocache
cipher AES-256-GCM
tls-client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns
setenv opt block-outside-dns # Prevent Windows 10 DNS leak
verb 3
route-nopull
pull-filter ignore route-ipv6
pull-filter ignore redirect-gateway
route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
route 192.168.84.0 255.255.255.0
route-ipv6 2403:ffff:ffff:ffff::/64 #redacted
route-ipv6 fd00:beef:b00b:cafe::/64
```

When both are activated you get these addresses and routes, and I see nothing conflicting. (I've redacted my IPv6 internet address for the server), but eth0 IPv6 is broken when the second OpenVPN service is running...

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 2404:ffff:ffff:ffff:216:3eff:fee2:12fe/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr 
       valid_lft 4sec preferred_lft 3sec
    inet6 fe80::216:3eff:fee2:12fe/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UNKNOWN qlen 500
    inet6 fd0a:beef:b00b:cafe::1/112 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::b9ec:b1f8:e65:7f3d/64 scope link stable-privacy 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: tun1: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UNKNOWN qlen 500
    inet6 fd08:beef:b00b:cafe::3/112 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::f807:1850:2b87:348/64 scope link stable-privacy 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
2403:ffff:ffff:ffff::/64 dev tun1 metric 1024 pref medium
2404:ffff:ffff::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256 expires 4sec pref medium
fd00:beef:b00b:cafe::/64 dev tun1 metric 1024 pref medium
fd08:beef:b00b:cafe::/112 dev tun1 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fd0a:beef:b00b:cafe::/112 dev tun0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev tun0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev tun1 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
default via fe80::ec4:7aff:fecc:1ca7 dev eth0 proto ra metric 1024 expires 1sec hoplimit 64 pref medium
default via fe80::ec4:7aff:fe7c:bf1f dev eth0 proto ra metric 1024 expires 4sec hoplimit 64 pref high
```

I am not sure what is wrong here, and the `openvpn@home` service does not seem to be assigning any default routes above, as my configuration file states. I don't understand why this breaks eth0 from getting any IPv6 traffic when the service is started. IPv4 works fine, and I seem to be able to get those LAN subnets in my client configuration. The other OpenVPN server is intended to provide internet, but I don't want that from it.

Answer (score 0):

I learned I was doing things on the wrong side, and instead changed the client configuration that connects to another OpenVPN server and simply commented out my static IPv6 routes.

```
#route-ipv6 2403:4800:3f02:1483::/64
#route-ipv6 fd00:beef:b00b:cafe::/64
```

Instead on that second server, I created a client configuration file in `/etc/openvpn/ccd` for this client that refers to it's IPv6 subnet as an iroute...

```
iroute-ipv6 fd08:beef:b00b:cafe::/64
```

Things started working!